# Webgl Buffer Values not working

Tags: webgl

i am learning WebGL right now and i saw this WebGL example from this site
http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/webgl-3d-perspective-matrix.html ,
where he has the same matrix and the same shader calculation as me, but i cant use his vertex data to draw the same object. Also i can only use negative z values between -1 and -2000, while he uses positive z values in his vertex data.
Why he can use positive z values ?

When i am using positive z values, then i see no triangle drawn.
Sorry for my bad English.

Here is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

var fs_str = " void main() { \n "
           + "gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);\n"
           + "} \n";
           
var vs_str = "attribute vec3 a_position;\n"
           + "uniform mat4 u_matrix;\n" 
           + " void main() { \n "
           + "vec4 position = u_matrix * vec4(a_position,1.0);\n"
           + "gl_Position = position;\n"
           + "}";
           
gl.clearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.viewport(0,0,canvas.clientWidth,canvas.clientHeight);


var program = gl.createProgram();

var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fs,fs_str);
gl.compileShader(fs);
gl.attachShader(program,fs);

var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vs,vs_str);
gl.compileShader(vs);
gl.attachShader(program,vs);

gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program);


var vertices = [-1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
                1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
                1.0, -1.0, -1.0 
               ];

 

var matrix = mat4.create();
mat4.perspective(matrix, (60 * Math.PI/ 180), canvas.clientWidth/canvas.clientHeight, 1, 2000);


var matrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"u_matrix");
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLocation,false,matrix);

var vbo = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"a_position");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation,3,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);

gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.2/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your point of view is at z = 0, looking towards the negatives. Setting a z in the positive will put the object behind you. On the website you linked, the Z value of the slider also can't go in the positives.

Also, because the last parameter of `mat4.perspective` is 2000, you won't be able to see anything that is more than 2000 units away from you. That is why -2000 is the maximum here.

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, for me your code is working as attended.

I made a fiddle including the "F" from the tutorial you are following :

https://jsfiddle.net/g69cdeza/1/

I added the line `mat4.translate(matrix, matrix, [5, 0, -500]);` to move the object.

Is there something more you are not managing to do?

Comment: Thank you ! My problem was I didnt think of an translation that move the object into the view. I get how the z values work, but i didnt get, why the "F" was showing in the example. But i know now it was though the translation.